# Could not find class, and yet it is there

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

When doing a `puppet agent` call from a new image, I'm getting a `err: Could not find class custommod` error. The module itself is in `/etc/puppet/modules/custommod` same as all of the other modules we're calling, but this one is obstinante.

[site.pp]

```
node /clunod-wk\d+\.sub\.example\.local/ {
      include base
      include curl
      include custommod
      class{ "custommod::apps": frontend => "false}
      [...]
}
```

When the puppetmaster is run with debug output, it clearly finding the information for base and curl:

```
debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/base/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported base from base into production
debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/curl/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported curl from curl into production
err: Could not find class custommod for clunod-wk0130.sub.example.local at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:84 on node clunod-wk0130.sub.example.local
```

Line 84 is `include custommod`

An abbreviated directory and file structure:

```
/etc/puppet
   |- manifests
   |     |- site.pp
   |
   |- modules
         |- base
         |    |- manifests
         |          |- init.pp
         |
         |- curl
         |    |- manifests
         |          |- init.pp
         |   
         |- custommod
              |- files 
              |     |- apps
              |         |- [...]
              |
              |- manifests
                    |- init.pp
                    |- apps.pp
```

I did check spelling :}

The content of `init.pp` in the custommod directory is completely unremarkable:

```
class custommod {
}
```

The intent is to create an empty class for the apps.pp file, which is where the meat is.

```
class custommod::apps {

    [lots of stuff]
}
```

Only, it's never getting to the apps file. If I comment out the `include custommod`, the above error is generated on the `class{ "custommod::apps": frontend => "false}` line instead.

What am I missing in my hunt to find out how this error is being generated? I need to note that this repo works just fine if it is run locally via `puppet apply`.

Comment: Did you take a peak in the client yaml file to see if your class is present?

Comment: @Zoredache The /var/lib/puppet/client_yaml/ directory is empty on the client. The client is getting a `could not retrieve catalog from remote server:` error which is probably why.

Comment: Hrm.. re-created your basic layout and import structure and couldn't reproduce the issue (on 2.7.1).  Should be safe to stop including the empty `custommod` - maybe even try deleting `init.pp` altogether, as it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @ShaneMadden After I try that, my next step is to throw `strace` at it and attempt to figure out what files it's attempting to read that way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So... this is a bit embarrassing, but...

Environments.

Right there in my `/etc/puppet.conf` file is this:

```
[master]
  manifest=$confdir/manifests/site.pp
  modulepath=$confdir/environments/$environment/modules:$confdir/modules
```

After throwing `strace` at it to figure out where it was hunting for files, I noticed something. It was looking for custommod under `/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules`, and since there was a directory there (empty), *it did not then go check `/etc/puppet/modules`*. Apparently when importing a module it checks for directory-presence, rather than file-presence (init.pp).

Remove that empty directory, things start working.

Run the puppet agent using a different environment, things start working.

Moral of the story:

> Puppet Environment paths do not act like bash $PATH.

Comment: And in case someone hasn't defined their modulepath explicitly in puppet.conf, and they want to find out puppet's modulepath without resorting to strace, they can also run `puppet config print modulepath`.

Comment: has this been reported to puppetlabs?

Comment: The modulepath now triggers a deprecation warning.

Comment: `modulepath` can no longer be set in `puppet.conf`

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem, but had a different fix

If you generate a puppet module like so:

```
puppet module generate foo-example_module
```

It will create a module named `example_module` with the `foo` name space. All the manifests will be inside a directory called `foo-example_module`

The name of the class defined in the init.pp needs to be the same as the folder name.

Simple fix:

```
mv foo-example_module example_module
```

If you run puppet-lint, it will warn with the following message:

```
ERROR: example_module not in autoload module layout on line 42
```

---

If using a Puppetfile with r10k or librarian-puppet, you also may need to remove the name space so that the files are placed without the 'foo' prefix in your modules directory.

before:

```
mod 'foo-example_module',
    :git => git@github.com:foo/example_module'
```

after:

```
mod 'example_module',
    :git => git@github.com:foo/example_module'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another problem that might happen is when your module have an invalid `metadata.json` file.

Make sure the `metadata.json` file have all the required fields (see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_metadata.html#allowed-keys-in-metadatajson )

Comment: Thank you, still helpful after quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar problem with puppet 3.7.1 for Fedora:
Could not find class puppet for my.server

Solution:

```
sudo ln -s /my/local/copy/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  In my case the class name was "onehost::change_IoT_password_reminder".  After using strace I found that puppet was looking for a modules/onehost/manifests/change_iot_password_reminder.pp file.  It seems using upper case letters in class names is not a good idea, even if it's not the first letter of the class.